# Real-time gunshot detection data?

Tags: usa, foia, real-time, crime

Was curious whether anyone had successfully obtained access to streaming data from any municipality that uses a "shots fired" detection system like [this one](http://www.shotspotter.com/).

According to their own documentation, the system itself is capable of generating an [xml feed](http://www.shotspotter.com/node/473), but I'm wondering if anyone has been able to obtain data via a public records request or similar action.

Comment: While this is an interesting request, I don't think that this type of data would be available real-time due to public safety issues.

Answer (score 3):

The City of Oakland tacitly agreed to make the shotspotter data open, and the firm representative was eager to do so, but they've not followed up by doing so.

They did release it in bulk in [Washington](http://www.washingtonpost.com/investigations/shotspotter-detection-system-documents-39000-shooting-incidents-in-the-district/2013/11/02/055f8e9c-2ab1-11e3-8ade-a1f23cda135e_story.html) however, not real time.