# Public access laws used for real-time data?

Tags: usa, legal, foia

In [a question about real-time gunshot data from Will Koper](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/815/263), he mentioned using public records laws to access it.

... which makes me wonder if anyone's even aware of FOIA or various state public records laws being used for real-time data access.  My understanding is that they aren't for open-ended access; you'd have to re-file each month for any new records created since the previous request was filed.

Is anyone aware of this working?  Or even any groups attempting to go this route?

Answer (score 1):

Given most local laws and regulations allow for a 2-3 week response time, I imagine you'd have to request the records before they exist, and word your request in such a way that it can "never" be completely fulfilled.